# Hash keys/values as function parameters

Tags: perl

I have the following perl code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use strict;
use warnings;
use Net::SSH::Perl;
sub SSH($$$$){             
          my ($host, $user, $pass, $cmd) = @_;
          my $ssh = Net::SSH::Perl->new($host);
          $ssh->login("$user", "$pass");
          return $ssh->cmd($cmd);
        };
        my %h = (
          "ILSW01" => {
                       "ip" => "1.1.1.",
                       "user" => "bla",
                       "pass" => "xxx"
                     }
                );
    SSH($h{host}{ip}, $h{host}{user}, $h{host}{pass}, "ls -ltr")
```

Works fine. 
**My question is, what if i have more than one host, how can i use the keys of the "host's hash" as parameters in the SSH function to avoid duplicate code writing ?**

**To to be clear: I want avoid using the SSH function per host**

Comment: Do you only want to call the SSH function once using variables, rather than make one call per host? I'm having trouble understanding.

Comment: Please give an example of what you would like to write, if there were multiple hosts in your hash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just pass your Hash of hosts and metadata to your SSH function:

```
sub SSH { 
   my (%h, $cmd) = @_;
   my @commands; 

   for my $host ( keys %h ) {
      my $ssh = New::SSH::Perl->new($host); 
      $ssh->login($h{$host}->{user}, $h{$host}->{pass});

      push @commands, 
         $ssh->cmd($cmd);
   }

   return @commands; 
}
```

Now you can call this function with as many hosts as you want, execute the remote commands and return a listing of the results;

Comment: Hunter McMillen -> Thank you

Answer (score 3):

> I want avoid using the SSH function per host

That sounds like a very poor design as you'd be combining unrelated two tasks in one function. I'd personally go with

```
my %hosts = (
   "ILSW01" => {
      host => "1.1.1.",
      user => "bla",
      pass => "xxx",
   },
   ...
);

sub SSH {
   my ($connect_info, $cmd) = @_;
   my $ssh = Net::SSH::Perl->new($connect_info->{host});
   $ssh->login($connect_info->{user}, $connect_info->{pass});
   return $ssh->cmd($cmd);
}

my @results = map { SSH($_, $cmd) } values(%hosts);
```

You can make a sub that consists of that last line if you really want a single sub, but I'm not sure there's much benefit to that here.

```
sub SSH_many {
    my ($hosts) = @_;
    return map { SSH($_, $cmd) } values(%$hosts);
}

my @results = SSH_many(\%hosts);
```

Answer (score 2):

First, don't use prototyping in Perl functions. [It is broken](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=861966). Well... not broken, it doesn't work the way you think it should work.

You want to pass multiple hashes into your subroutine. Each containing three values:

- The IP address
- The User Name
- The Password

In Perl, the basic data structures all pass *scalar* data. Variables like `$foo` contain a single piece of scalar data. Variables like `@foo` contain a list of scalar data, and variables like `%foo` contain a key/value set of scalar data. However, not all data is *scalar*. Some of it has a complex structure. The question is how to emulate this structure in Perl.

The way we do this in Perl is through *references*. A reference is a location in memory where my data is stored.

For example, my FTP location is a hash with three pieces of data:

```
my %ftp_user;
$ftp_user{IP}       = 1.1.1.1;
$ftp_user{USRER}    = "foo";
$ftp_user{PASSWORD} = "swordfish";
```

I can get a *reference* to this hash by putting a backslash in front of it:

```
my $ftp_user_ref = \%ftp_user;
```

Note the `$` in front of the `$ftp_user_ref` variable. This means that the value in `$ftp_user_ref` is a *scalar* bit of data. I can put that into an array:

```
push @ftp_users_list, $ftp_user_ref;
```

Now my `@ftp_users_list` contains an array of entire hashes, and not an array of individual scalar pieces of data.

I can even take a reference of my `@ftp_users_list`:

```
my $ftp_user_list_ref = \@ftp_users_list;
```

And, I can pass that into my subroutine as a single piece of data.

Take a look at the [Perl Reference Tutorial](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html) that comes with Perl and learn how references work and how you can use them.

Meanwhile, here's an example that uses references to call each host and run a series of commands. Note that my `ssh` subroutine takes just two parameters: An array of hashes that are my login credentials for each system, and a list of my commands I want to run on each system:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
#
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);

my @ftp_list;
while ( my $line = <DATA> ) {
    chomp $line;
    my ($ip, $user, $password) = split /:/, $line;
    # Push an anonymous hash into my @ftp_list
    push @ftp_list, { IP => $ip, USER => $user, PASSWORD => $password };
}
my @commands;
push @commands, "cd data";
push @commands, "get foo.txt";
push @commands, "del foo.txt";
ssh( \@ftp_list, \@commands );

sub ssh {
    my $ftp_list_ref = shift;
    my $commands_ref = shift;

    my @ftp_list = @{ $ftp_list_ref };
    my @commmands = @{ $commands_ref };

    for my $ip_ref ( @ftp_list ) {
        my $ip = $ip_ref->{IP};
        my $user = $ip_ref->{USER};
        my $pass = $ip_ref->{PASSWORD};

        say "my \$ssh = Net::SSH::Perl->new($ip);";
        say "\$ssh->login($user, $pass);";
        for my $command ( @commands ) {
            my $results = say "\$ssh->cmd($command);";
            return if not defined $results;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
__DATA__
1.1.1.1:bob:swordfish
1.2.3.2:carol:secret
1.3.4.5:lewis:ca$h
```